# Оформить функцию поиска номера последнего положительного элемента в массиве

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Оформить функцию поиска номера последнего положительного элемента в массиве. В главной программе дано 2 одномерных массива a, b длиной 15 элементов каждый. Применить функцию для каждого из 2-х заданных массивов. Найти произведение
найденных номеров элементов. Написал, но выходят ошибки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int min = -100;
const int max = 100;

int ret_ind(int arr[], int len)
{
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) if (arr[i] > -1) k = i;

    return k;
}

int main()
{
    int a[15], b[15];

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        a[i] = min + rand() % (max - min);
        b[i] = min + rand() % (max - min);
        cout << (i + 1) << " " << a[i] << " " << b[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Res = " << (ret_ind(a, 15)*ret_ind(b, 15)) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то странно вы ищете индекс последнего положительного элемента...

Его проще искать с конца:

```
int ret_ind(int arr[], int len)
{
    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (arr[i] > 0) return i;
    return -1; // Все отрицательные или нулевые
}
```